# Can I save the plot output from seaborn as a shp file?

Tags: python, seaborn, geojson, geopandas

I am trying to create a Kernel Density Plot through Python and save it as a shape file.

Through Seaborn, I have drawn the Kernel Density Plot like this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoLMe.jpg), but I do not know how can I save it as a shape file.

I have used GeoPandas, GeoJson, and other features, but I still can not find the answer.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = sns.kdeplot(Cood_Wgs84_Array, shade = True, cmap = "PuBu")

ax.patch.set_facecolor('white')
ax.collections[0].set_alpha(0)

plt.show()
```

Comment: not really, shape file is for geospatial vector data.

Comment: If you're looking to use a KDE plot with spatial data, you may want to look into `geoplot` (see https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/kdeplot.html)